# ¿Como "expandir" una matriz?

Tags: r, algoritmos, matrices

Partiendo de una matriz como la siguiente:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

quisiera generar una nueva, dónde cada elemento se expanda por ejemplo, a sub-matrices de digamos 2 x 2. Por ejemplo:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    3    3
[2,]    1    1    3    3
[3,]    2    2    4    4
[4,]    2    2    4    4
```

Idealmente, debiera aplicarse también a matrices rectangulares, por ejemplo una matriz como está:

```
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
```

Se debería expandir a 3 y transformarse en algo así:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
[4,]    2    2    2
[5,]    2    2    2
[6,]    2    2    2
```

Vale cualquier tipo de aproximación al problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad puede emplearse bucles `for` anidados, pero indexado la matriz que contendrá la respuesta, si bien **R** cuenta con otras funciones y paquetes que permiten conseguir lo mismo, lo desarrollé con ese enfoque porque podría facilitar su portabilidad a otros lenguajes de programación:

```
expandMatriz <- function(m, r=2){
    v <- as.vector(m)   # convertimos la matriz en vector
    f <- dim(m)[1]      # filas de m
    c <- dim(m)[2]      # columnas de m

    # matriz base que contendrá la expansión de los datos en `m`
    ans <- matrix(0, nrow=f*r, ncol=c*r)

    # se crean submatrices identicas a partir de cada elemento de v
    for(j in 1:c) { 
        for(i in 1:f) {
           ans[ ((i-1)*r+1):(i*r), ((j-1)*r+1):(j*r) ] <- v[ (j-1)*f + i ]
        }
    }
    ans
}
```

Aplicándolo al siguiente ejemplo

```
m <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)
expandMatriz(m, r=3)

# matriz m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

# reporte indexado
[1] "1-1: [1:3] [1:3] <- 1"
[1] "2-1: [4:6] [1:3] <- 2"
[1] "1-2: [1:3] [4:6] <- 3"
[1] "2-2: [4:6] [4:6] <- 4"

# matriz expandida en 3
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    3    3    3
[2,]    1    1    1    3    3    3
[3,]    1    1    1    3    3    3
[4,]    2    2    2    4    4    4
[5,]    2    2    2    4    4    4
[6,]    2    2    2    4    4    4
```

> Nótese que los bucles anidados `for` no condicionan su crecimiento en función de `r` (radio de crecimiento de cada elemento en la matriz `m`) sino en función a los elementos contenidos en el vector `v`. Para que se entienda lo anterior aquí otro alcance.

```
m <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
expandMatriz(m, r=3)

 # matriz m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

# reporte indexado
[1] "1-1: [1:3] [1:3] <- 1"
[1] "2-1: [4:6] [1:3] <- 2"
[1] "3-1: [7:9] [1:3] <- 3"
[1] "1-2: [1:3] [4:6] <- 4"
[1] "2-2: [4:6] [4:6] <- 5"
[1] "3-2: [7:9] [4:6] <- 6"
[1] "1-3: [1:3] [7:9] <- 7"
[1] "2-3: [4:6] [7:9] <- 8"
[1] "3-3: [7:9] [7:9] <- 9"

# matriz expandida en 3
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    1    1    1    4    4    4    7    7    7
 [2,]    1    1    1    4    4    4    7    7    7
 [3,]    1    1    1    4    4    4    7    7    7
 [4,]    2    2    2    5    5    5    8    8    8
 [5,]    2    2    2    5    5    5    8    8    8
 [6,]    2    2    2    5    5    5    8    8    8
 [7,]    3    3    3    6    6    6    9    9    9
 [8,]    3    3    3    6    6    6    9    9    9
 [9,]    3    3    3    6    6    6    9    9    9
```

Es decir se efectúa un uso adecuado de los bucles `for` anidados:

```
system.time(expandMatriz( matrix(1:10000, nrow = 100), r=3))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.018   0.000   0.018
```

> La función `expandMatriz` sólo funciona para un `r>=2` y con matrices de `NxM` dimensiones, donde: `N` y `M` no necesariamente son iguales.

Por ejemplo en el post se pide

```
m <- matrix(1:2, nrow = 2)
m
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
```

Y que sea expandida rectángularmente en tres, Esto se puede conseguir:

```
expandMatriz(m, r=3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
[4,]    2    2    2
[5,]    2    2    2
[6,]    2    2    2
```

Finalmente los reportes de indexado que se mostraron, han sido obtenidos con lo siguiente, dentro de los bucles `for`:

```
print(
       paste0( i,"-",j,
                ": [",
               ((i-1)*r+1),":",(i*r),
               "] [", 
                ((j-1)*r+1),":",(j*r),
               "] <- ",
                (j-1)*f + i )
     )
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta podría ser una forma:

```
grow_matrix <- function(mat, by) {

    d <- dim(mat)
    v <- rep(mat,each=by)
    matrix(unlist(rep(split(rep(mat,each=by), rep(1:d[2], each=d[1]*by)), each=by)), nrow = by*d[1])

}
```

La idea es trabajar la matriz como un vector plano, generar las repeticiones para cada valor y luego reordenarlos de cierta forma. para mantener el orden original cuando volvamos a transformar el vector en una matriz. El parámetro `by` hace referencia a cuanto deseamos hacer crecer cada valor en cada dimensión.

```
m <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)
grow_matrix(m, 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    3    3
[2,]    1    1    3    3
[3,]    2    2    4    4
[4,]    2    2    4    4
```